# How to extract a string from a Pandas dataframe and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strsplit, newrow

I start from a pandas dataframe with this columns:

```
Name:    'Computer', 'Tablet', 'Monitor'
Price:   900, 300, 400
Identifier:  '11$10qw-IDAA', '2222-IL$DB123', '2237-12$33AVD-ewwfq'
```

I would like to create a new column (for example a NewString) of the data frame which extracts
substrings from the Identifier column that contain the $ character.
That is, I would like to add the column with the values to the df:

```
NewString
11$10qw
IL$DB123
12$33AVD
```

I tried to do it with two nested for loops: one that loops over all the rows of the df, and
inside another loop that works on the list formed by the split on the "Identifier" column, but I can't solve it

Comment: it looks like here the separatore is '-' and you want new string to be poppulated by element containing `$` isn't?

Comment: I would like the "Identifier" column to be first divided into strings separated by the "-" character and, among these, only that string containing the "$" character is extracted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['out'] = df['Identifier'].str.extract(r'([^-]*\$[^-]*)', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
       Name  Price           Identifier       out
0  Computer    900         11$10qw-IDAA   11$10qw
1    Tablet    300        2222-IL$DB123  IL$DB123
2   Monitor    400  2237-12$33AVD-ewwfq  12$33AVD
```